# How to list the upcoming latest events in jquery full calendar?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar with some events. When the user hovers to a particular event it will show a popover about the event with title and message given in the event.json. What i want to achieve is , to display the latest upcoming events(5-6) at the bottom of the calendar in a div.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cal.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ctrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "kupArj.json",
        success: function(data) {

            eventData = data;
            eventDataFn(eventData);
        }
    });

    /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {


        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
        });

    });



    /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function eventDataFn(eventData) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.popover({
                    title: event.title,
                    placement: 'auto',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    animation: 'true',
                    content: event.msg
                });
                $('body').on('click', function(e) {
                    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                        element.popover('hide');
                });
            },
            events: eventData
        });
    }


});
```

Comment: What is the question? `here is the code` doesn't tell anyone what is or isn't working or where you have problems

Comment: @charlietfl the question is how to list the upcoming events from the current date.. ( see the question which is in block letters)

Comment: subject question all by itself is too broad by itself. What have you tried? It sounds like you want someone to write the code for you

Comment: @charlietfl i don't know how to achieve that ? thats why i am seeking help to achieve

Comment: I, too, need help doing something like what is being requested. not sure how to start.